# Razor Pages - Returning Model Value

Tags: .net-core, model-binding, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor pages and having trouble with model binding back to the view.

I'm using VS2019 version 16.0.4.

This is my PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        PageIndex++;
        return Page();
    }
}
```

And my View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PageIndex"></label>
        <input asp-for="PageIndex" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="PageIndex"></span>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Increment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would expect the value displayed in the input control to be incremented on each click - but it remains at zero. The binding into the controller seems to work ok. If I enter a value of "5" and click the button then a breakpoint shows me that a value of 5 is received before being incremented to 6. However, the incremented value does not get reflected back to the view.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding takes values from the HTTP request and binds them to handler method parameters or PageModel properties. It is not two-way, and does not then bind those values back to the controls where the values originated.

You need to explicitly set the `value` attribute of the input to see the behaviour that you expect:

```
<input asp-for="PageIndex" value="@Model.PageIndex" />
```